# Show the value of the nearest non-empty above cell

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, excel-formula

I need to reveal the value of the nearest non-empty above cell.
In some cases, a direct reference.
In other cases, the value + 1.

This is my attempt, however, `Cell.End()` is a VBA function, so it is not dynamic, as expansion of the table can't inherit the pattern.

`Const CELL_FML_L As String = "=If(Indirect(""A""&Row()-1)=""#"",1,Indirect(""A""&"`

`Const CELL_FML_R As String = ")+1)"`

Within a `For Each Cell In [Table]` loop

`Cell.FormulaR1C1 = CELL_FML_L & Cell.End(xlUp).Row & CELL_FML_R`

Is there any way to achieve that entirely with the Excel formula?

Comment: What is `CELL_FML_R`? Where is that defined?...part of the For loop?

Comment: My bad. They were wrote in chunks.

Comment: you may want to share some more info/example of what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

As you've used a VBA tag, maybe a UDF:

```
Public Function FindPrevious(Target As Range) As Variant

    'Application.Volatile  'Uncomment to make function volatile -
                           'Recalculates whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the worksheet

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        FindPrevious = CVErr(xlErrRef) 'Return #REF! error.
    Else
        Dim rTmp As Range
        Set rTmp = Target.EntireColumn.Find(What:="*", After:=Target, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If Not rTmp Is Nothing Then
            If rTmp.Row < Target.Row Then
                FindPrevious = rTmp.Value
            Else
                FindPrevious = CVErr(xlErrNull) 'Return #NULL! error
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Never know the Observer pattern can be applied rather than 'Worksheet_SelectionChange'. My friend recommended 'COUNTA()' and 'INDIRECT()'& 'Row()'. Thank you! Will update if solved.